# How can I remove index from output

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I need to remove index from my output because I need to calculate the difference between two times then display it.
I tried adding  `index=False` but it did not work.
I can't use `df.to_string(index=False)` because then, I won't be able to use it in my calculation when it's converted to a string.
This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('File.xlsx',header=0, index= False)
df.index.name = None
#print (df.to_string(index=False))
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])

x=df.loc[df.b == '[0]->[1]', 'Time']
print ('\nx= ',x)
startDateTime= df.iloc[0,2]
print('\nstartDateTime ',startDateTime)
#if 3rd column is filled by datetimes
endDateTime=x
print('\nendDateTime ',endDateTime)
diff = endDateTime - startDateTime
print('difference is ',diff)
```

output :

```
x=  16073   2018-11-28 14:11:42.341599
```

desired output

```
x=   2018/11/28 14:11:42.341599
```

when I removed `.loc` from the line

```
x=df.loc[df.b == '[0]->[1]', 'Time']
```

I got TypeError.
**PS**: the final result, `diff = endDateTime - startDateTime` is correct but it's not well displayed `difference is  16073   00:04:22.670328`
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe try `print('difference is ', diff.tolist())` or `print('difference is ', diff.values)`.

Comment: I added `iloc[0]` to the line `x=df.loc[df.Payload == 'a[0]->[1]', 'Time'].iloc[0]` and it worked. Thanks!